# Error: '-' is not a valid resource name character in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I created a new Google Maps Activity, and the only thing I did was stick my API key into the .xml file. When I run the project, I get an: "Error: '-' is not a valid resource name character" in the .xml file. What is wrong with the project, and how can I fix the error?
[.xml file error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TYEF.png)

Comment: check your .xml resource file.you declare the some resource with - (hyphen) and android not allow a use of hyphen in resource file name of resource ids so check it once

Comment: see this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=31

Comment: The only hyphen I have in the .xml file is the hyphen in the API key, no other "-"s in the entire file.

Comment: I added a screenshot of Android Studio with the error.

Comment: issue in google_maps_api.xml

Comment: I changed the screenshot

Comment: there is hyphen in your key..

Comment: try to create new API key and add it,,thats only way to solve i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your android studio on google_maps_api.xml there will something like this :

You can also add your credentials to an existing key, using this line:
    47:2A:E4:BC:00:1D:21:E2:FA:20:B9:AB:70:FB:75:E7:23:16:37:C1;com.example.radio.demomap

notice that it is separated by a semicolon

47:2A:E4:BC:00:1D:21:E2:FA:20:B9:AB:70:FB:75:E7:23:16:37:C1 ; com.example.radio.demomap

now when you go to google console developer to create credentials

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrw3F.png)

type your package name and fingerprint certificate key and enter create you will get your correct key

Answer (score 6):

i had this error, mainly it is where you place the key...
Replace the YOUR_KEY in the code with your API key that start with Alza

from

```
 <string name="google_maps_key"
    templateMergeStrategy="preserve"
    translatable="false">YOUR_KEY</string>
```

to

```
 <string name="google_maps_key"
    templateMergeStrategy="preserve"
    translatable="false">AIzaSyBs8wUvJW-zOZixEiPmedagyrW8Y7VcW4I</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put the key this way:

```
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">**YOUR_KEY**</string>
```

Not this way:

```
 <string name="**YOUR_KEY**" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false"></string>
```

Comment: Ahh... I'm an idiot. To be fair, the comment block is a bit misleading when it says `Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
    string in this file.`